# CSS rotateY update img src not visible until transition complete

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to rotate one image to another, selecting a new image source from an array each time.

I'm updating the src for the back image before I apply a class to perform the transition.  But the images doesn't change until after the transition.  So you actually see the old image rotate and then it switches to the new one after the transition is complete.

This will be used in a grid of images but have stripped down to a single item. 
See codepen:
https://codepen.io/designseeds/pen/WywNjj

```js
//Array of available images
var imageArray = ["https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=0", "https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=10", "https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=20", "https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=30", "https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=40", "https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=50", "https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=60", "https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=70", "https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=80", "https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=90", "https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=100", "https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=110"]

//The gallery
var galleryContainer = $('#gallery');

//How many items
const itemsTotal = 1;

var i;
for (i = 0; i < itemsTotal; i++) {
    let src = imageArray[0];
    galleryContainer.prepend(`<div class="card">
    <img class="front" src="${src}">
    <img class="back" src="${src}">
  </div>`);
    imageArray.splice(0, 1);
}
//Get reference to gallery images
var galleryCards = $('#gallery .card');


//The item in the array to replace the src with
var nextImage = 0;
//Reference to the element that will be transitioned
var currentImage = 0;

function init() {
    randomImg();
}

function imageSetup() {
    var card = galleryCards.eq(currentImage);
    var cardFront = card.find('.front');
    var cardBack = card.find('.back');

    if (card.hasClass('is-flipped')) {
        var replaceImg = cardFront;
        var currentImgSrc = cardBack.attr('src');
    } else {
        var replaceImg = cardBack;
        var currentImgSrc = cardFront.attr('src');
    }

    //Src for new image
    var newImg = imageArray[nextImage];

    //Remove image from array and replace with removed image
    imageArray.splice(nextImage, 1, currentImgSrc);

    replaceImg.attr('src', newImg);


    setTimeout(imageRotate, 4000);
}

function imageRotate(card) {

    var card = galleryCards.eq(currentImage);
    card.toggleClass('is-flipped');

    //Added this timeout to be sure the css transition has finisehd before starting again
    setTimeout(randomImg, 4000);
    //randomImg();
}

function randomImg() {

    currentImage = Math.floor((Math.random() * itemsTotal));
    nextImage = Math.floor((Math.random() * imageArray.length));
    currentImage = 0;

    imageSetup();
}
```

```css
#gallery {
  max-width:400px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  perspective: 600px;
 
}
#gallery .card {
  width:calc(100%/3);
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:calc(100%/3);
  
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card img {
  transition: transform 1s;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  max-width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

img.back {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.card.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#images {
/*   display:none; */
}
#images img{
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Gallery</h4>
<button onclick="init()">Click me</button>
<div id="gallery">
</div>
<!--ADD this for testing to be sure images have loaded.-->
<div id="images"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=0">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=10">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=20">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=30">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=40">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=50">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=60">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=70">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=80">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=90">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=100">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=110"></div>
```

I'm guessing as the image is out of view the browser isn't picking up the change and then waits until the transition is over.

This is an issue in Chrome 66 and safari 11.
Here's a quick screencast of the issue i'm getting.
[Screencast of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orc9E.gif)

Comment: Seems to work perfectly for me... The image flips to reveal the new one, as expected.

Comment: Strange, i've added to the question a quick screencast of what i'm seeing.  So you see it rotate the laptop image and the once the transition is complete it changes to the sunset image, which is the image it should actually be.